# Center origin of a Scatter Chart

Tags: chart.js, vue-chartjs

I read the docs, searched on Google, SO, but impossible to find a way to center the origin.

[image]

What I want is to have (0,0) on the middle and my black point at the top right (more or less).

Is it possible to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

Set the min and max range of your axes so that they extend from negative to positive.  This will put (0, 0) in the middle.

[image: chart.js centered scatter axis]

Example code below:

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'scatter',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Data One',
      borderColor: 'black',
      backgroundColor: 'black',
      data: [{
        x: 7,
        y: 27,
      }],
    }],
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: -30,
          max: 30,
        },
      }, ],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: -30,
          max: 30,
        },
      }],
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.js" integrity="sha512-QEiC894KVkN9Tsoi6+mKf8HaCLJvyA6QIRzY5KrfINXYuP9NxdIkRQhGq3BZi0J4I7V5SidGM3XUQ5wFiMDuWg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>
  <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: Yeah good idea ! And I can update min and max by my maximum values each time I add a coordinate so that the chart scales ?

Comment: That's right, it seems you would have to manually determine min/max yourself based on the range of your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api) that offers a range of hooks that may be used for performing custom code. In the `beforeDraw` for example, you can compute and set the [`ticks.padding`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html#tick-configuration) of both axes in order to move the `ticks` to the desired position.

```
beforeDraw: chart => {
  var xAxis = chart.scales['x-axis-1'];
  var yAxis = chart.scales['y-axis-1'];
  const scales = chart.chart.config.options.scales;
  scales.xAxes[0].ticks.padding = yAxis.top - yAxis.getPixelForValue(0) + 6;
  scales.yAxes[0].ticks.padding = xAxis.getPixelForValue(0) - xAxis.right + 6;
}
```

Please take a look at the runnable code below and see how it works.

```js
new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'scatter',
  plugins:[{
    beforeDraw: chart => {
      var xAxis = chart.scales['x-axis-1'];
      var yAxis = chart.scales['y-axis-1'];
      const scales = chart.chart.config.options.scales;
      scales.xAxes[0].ticks.padding = yAxis.top - yAxis.getPixelForValue(0) + 6;
      scales.yAxes[0].ticks.padding = xAxis.getPixelForValue(0) - xAxis.right + 6;
    }
  }],
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Data One',
      data: [{x:7,y:27}],
      backgroundColor: 'black'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: -30,
          max: 30,
          stepSize: 5,
          callback: v => v == 0 ? '' : v
        },
        gridLines: {
          drawTicks: false
        }        
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: -30,
          max: 30,
          stepSize: 5,
          callback: v => v == 0 ? '' : v
        },
        gridLines: {
          drawTicks: false
        } 
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="1" height="1"></canvas>
```